# Convert API: What is the maximum file size we can upload through HTTP Request

Tags: pdf, filesize, convertapi

I am trying to split PDF into pages if it exceeds the file size of 20mb, Need to know what is the maximum file size that we can upload through Convert API HTTP Request

Tried up to 60mb of files after some retries it's working, Need to know the exact file size limit.